# AngularJS ng-style is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to apply background color on a `div` using AngularJS `ng-style`. My colors are coming from a database. It is not working for me. Can anybody help me.

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <div style="width: 500px;">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>      
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="color in colors">
                <tr ng-show="edit">
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="color.ID" ng-change="color.changed=true" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" ng-model="color.Name" colorpicker ng-change="color.changed=true" />
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" ng-click="edit=false; save();" /> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-hide="edit">
                    <td><strong>{{color.ID}}</strong> </td>
                    <td><div style="width:20px; height:20px; border:thin solid black" ng-model="color.Name" ng-style="{'background-color' : color.Name}"></div> </td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Edit" ng-click="edit=true;" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is colorpicker a directive you wrote?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: btw. what's up with defining `ng-model` on a `div` element? I have seen it a couple times now but I don't quite get what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I more than believe that ng-repeat on tbody is incorrect.

Comment: Yes colorpicker is a directive

Comment: I have removed ng-model from div I don't need it.

Comment: ng-repeat is working fine. it creating rows but only thing is ng-style which is not working.

Comment: ng-repeat creates N time tbody

Comment: r u looking for something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/LV96s0szWbBFkzCCKfpJ?p=preview

Comment: no it is not repeating tbody. I saw in my DOM by inspect element. Event I changed it and added ng-repeat on row and I have removed the ng-show and ng-hide and now I have only one row.. but it is not working at all.

Comment: Thank you so much.. your example on plnkr is working fine for me.. great!

Comment: good. let's close Question then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/LV96s0szWbBFkzCCKfpJ?p=preview

this is more like you need. take a look.

Comment: Some code and an explanation of the changes seem like a minimum requirement here.